# Avoid entering URLs manually in the React components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gatsby

I am taking my first steps with Gatsby, and I find that I am repeating myself frequently. One example is making links, where in several places I do something like:

```
import {kebabCase} from "lodash";

// ...
    <Link to={`tags/${kebabCase(tag)}`}>
      {tag}
    </Link>
```

It feels wrong to create the `to` argument in several places, and when I decide to change the URL format (for example: `tag/...` instead of `tags/...`) I will have to change all occurrences.

I know that the Django framework solves this by using "named urls". You can identify the URL by keyword, and provide arguments. It will then return the properly formatted URL. Is something like this part of Gatsby or React, or any other way to solve this?

Naively, my code example would be:

```
import {urlmaker} from "urlutil"

//...
    <Link to={urlmaker(`tag`, { tagname: {tag} })}>
      {tag}
    </Link>
```

I think this is not too hard to implement myself, but I am curious for any standardized React or Gatsby way to handle this.

Comment: You can declare those path prefixes as constants and import them?

Comment: @riwu That would take care of this small use case, but not -for instance- if you decide to add a date portion to your blogpost URL.

Comment: Wouldn't the date already be a variable?

Comment: Imagine I want to go from `blog/my-post/` to `blog/2018-04-06_my-post.html`. Preferably there would be one place to handle this.

Comment: Then you declare it as function or something: `const getPostURL = (prefix, postfix) => \`prefix${my-post}postfix\``. Over-engineering imo but if you want that much flexibility without changing your other code...

Comment: How do you envision a library can help you to do that?

Comment: Well, anything that implements `urlmaker` from my code example would be a help. I don't think it would be hard to code up myself, but the use case should be so common that I imagine it is somehow part of the default React library. I just found [this](https://github.com/adamziel/react-router-named-routes) and perhaps it does the trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Posting this as an answer, but hopefully somebody more knowledgable will come up with a more standardized approach.*

The functionality I require can be achieved by creating an object to take care of the routes.

`utilities/routing.js`

```
import {kebabCase} from "lodash";

export const makeRoute = {
  tagPage: ({tag}) => `/tag/${kebabCase(tag)}/`,
  blogPage: ({title, date}) => `/blog/${date}_${kebabCase(title)}/`
};
```

Now you have defined the routes in a central place, for use in your React components or other configuration files:

`component.js`

```
import {makeRoute} from "../utilities/routing";
...
        <Link to={ makeRoute.tagPage({tag}) }>
          {tag}
        </Link>
```

For consistency in Gatsby, also use this method to in the `createPage` api. Gatsby registers the pages in React-router and we want them to match up, obviously.

`gatsby-node.js`

```
import {makeRoute} from "utilities/routing";
...
    createPage({
      path: makeRoute.tagPage({tag}),
      component: path.resolve("./src/templates/tag.js"),
      context: { tag, },
    });
```

Answer (score 3):

You can define a constant globally and utilize it so that you only need to change the value where you have defined the constant when you need it. For eg. you may define development and production environment constant:

```
// Development Environment
const TAGS = 'tags';

// Production Environment
const TAGS = 'pro-tags';
```

And then you can simply use that constant.

```
<Link to={`${TAGS}/${kebabCase(tag)}`}>
```

Now, when your app runs in production environment, it will be 'pro-tags' and so on.

---

**Update:** You can also make a component and utilize the props to route the link, following is just an example:

```
export class OptionalLink extends React.Component {

    render( ) {

     return this.props.dateProp
       ? <Link to={`${this.props.dateProp}/${this.props.pathProp}`} {... this.props} />
       : <Link to={`${someDefaultDate}/${this.props.pathProp}}`} { ... this.props} />;

    }
};
```

Now, you can use `<OptionalLink dateProps="2018-apr-23" pathProp={kebabCase(tag)} />`

I hope you can manage this way.

Comment: I was really looking for a more general solution, where you define the URLs in one place. See also my comment on @riwu above

Comment: @RoyPrins You can declare all the URL constants in one file to achieve "define the URLs in one place"?

Comment: Thanks for the update, but it is still does not provide a standardized and central way to handle routes. The path is not only needed in the components, but also in other places like Gatby's `createPage` api. The way Django handles paths is really superior.

Comment: You can utilize default props value as many as you want. This is just a path to workout for you. You can utilize all the props in this component using switch statement

Comment: Updated my example. Hope, it makes sense now to you.

Comment: It makes sense, but it does not really address the requirements in my case. I will make a custom solution, but still hope that somebody can provide a standardized way to do this.